# Is there an API (any language) to add an App from SharePoint store? Without to do it manually?

Tags: api, office365, sharepoint-online

There's no PowerShell cmdlet provided by Microsoft to add an app from the SharePoint Store. The Cmdlet install-SPApp only works with imported packages in the App Catalog which is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such API to add an App from SharePoint store. You have to do it manually.

Comment: Is adding app from SharePoint store now supported by API/Site Script Action or Power Automate Flow Action? I didn't find any article related to this request.